# Android debugging on device - LogCat doesn't work!

Tags: android, debugging, nexus-one

Hi I use Nexus One to debug my project...

But when connected to computer (with Debugging mode ON) no Log is in Debug mode (Eclipse). The app is installed ad started from computer, but logs don't show...

What can I do? And idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try switching to the Android Perspective (DDMS). There should be a list of all running devices connected to the ADB. Select the device you're using and the LogCat should be displayed.

Comment: Great! It worked when restarting Eclipse again! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Problem then seems to be that you do not get stoped at breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that your Nexus One is recognized by ADB by typing `adb devices`.

Is it there? (on Windows you will need a [device driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) for the Nexus One).

Then, type `ddms` to invoke the DDMS view independently of Eclipse.

Comment: I checked that before! Thanks for your time!