# GoogleJSONResponseException

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I tried to start using Google Cloud Console and followed after the Google IO tutorial for Geek Serendipity http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5u_Owtbfew. I followed all the steps of the tutorial, however, I get an error every time I try to send a request to server. Neither logcat, nor Eclipse console gave any errors, however, I see a toast in the application that says

> com.google.apiclient.apis.json.GoogleJSONResponseException:503 Service unavailable... "reason": backend error.

However, in google appengine logs there are no recent error.

Has anyone faced same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you ensure the following:

1) Check that you have set PROJECT_ID correctly in the Consts.java

2) You should definitely see the same message in LogCat. Check this answer to get your LogCat working:
[Android debugging on device - LogCat doesn't work!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869095/android-debugging-on-device-logcat-doesnt-work)

Once LogCat works, you should see the same Exception there, along with another exception such as SocketTimeoutException, or something else that will give you an idea of what went wrong.